# Plesk 10 : separate http and https content

Tags: https, subdomain, plesk

I know that in Plesk 10 all content should be placed inside the httpdocs folder.

But then how do you differentiate between what needs to be secured (ssl, like a login-based site) and what does not needs to be secured (a public website)?

Another question: if I create a subdomain "secure" (secure.mydomain.tld) to contain my old https-documents, how do I make it accessible only with https:// and not with common http?

There are passwords to be filled in and I want to use HTTPS to secure this.
Anyone attempting http://secure.mydomain.tld should be redirected to https://secure.mydomain.tld.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a .htaccess to do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule (.*) https://yourdomain/$1 [R,L]
```